# What camera should I buy and what do I need to look for?

Tags: camera-recommendation

I want to start photography as an hobby. So to start I need a camera. I now a reflex would be the best, but I have no idea what to look for: pixels or ISO. What would the most adapted lens for landscape pictures. I'm ready to spend a maximum of 500$ in a camera.

Comment: The question is too braod. At least, address the following points: (a) budget for both camera and lens (b) your degree of inclination, i.e. how enthusiastic you are (c) the genre of photography you are interested in (d) goal - just for fun or wanting to commercialise (e) any market research you have done. Beware that people out here are not very keen to answer product recommendations queries, because of short-life of such questions.

Comment: The quality of cameras has improved considerably in the last few years (e.g. the noise will be much lower, dynamic range will have improved a lot), so today you'll get better results buying a cheaper camera to save money for a better lens (ditch the kit lens in favor of a better one and chose a camera that will allow you to do so within your budget).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

More Pixels are only useful for printing bigger images at a given print quality. 10 or 12 MP (megapixels) is enough for normal sized prints. Manufacturers add more MP to attract new buyers who think MP is very important. If you search a lot, even pro cameras like the Nikon D4 only have 16-20 megapixels.

Comment: Why -1 ? Did I say something wrong ? Pls correct me

Comment: Hi Jana, and welcome to Stack Exchange. I don't know why someone downvoted, but I suspect it was simply because it's generally better to mark this sort of "zero research" question closed and move on rather than rewarding them with answers. Or, it may be someone who thinks that more megapixels actually do deliver value (for which a decent case can be made).

Comment: Or it could be someone thinking "OMG you didn't tell him what camera to go to the store and buy right now". Overall, I wouldn't worry too much about one downvote.